# How to disable git bash daily updates checking?

Tags: installation, git, git-bash

I've installed git bash and ticked the "Check daily for updates" option. I thought that it will update automatically, but it requires me to configure the set up manually each time. I don't update it but it annoys me every day. When I tried to install a new version of git with that option unchecked it still was left intact. Is there a way to remove the daily checking or should I just reinstall my git bash with that option unselected?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I too encountered this really annoying "automatic update" behavior. It looks like checking this box during install adds a scheduled task to the Windows task scheduler. You ought to be able to remove it from here.

[image: Task Scheduler with Git Update Scheduled Task]

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. I was going to test if the updates will really disappear and forgot to mark this as an accepted answer afterwards. :D

Comment: Worked thanks.   Also thank git for using a standard and easily configurable mechanism for scheduling things on windows...i changed it to twice a year.